# C function calling problems in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

```
section .data
text db 'Put a number',10,0
scanform db '%d'
number dw 0

section .text
extern printf,scanf

global main
main:
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
push rdi
push rsi
push rbx

mov rdi,text
mov rax,0
call printf

mov rsi,number
mov rdi,scanform
mov rax,0
call scanf

pop rbx
pop rsi
pop rdi
ret
```

This is my code I write a other codes all day and I do not have problem with these but now when I call scanf, write program received signal SIGSEV, segfault... Specified first and last line in different files. I do not understand this message can someone help me?

Comment: You misaligned the stack. Also, you forgot to `pop rbp`.

Comment: Can you write my code on right way?

Comment: Shouldn't `scanform` be null-terminated too?

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić, no. Better if you write your code the right way, using the suggestions in the comment(s).

Comment: I write mov rsp,rbp, then pop rbp but again i get a seg.fault

Comment: Just remove the `push rdi`/`rsi`/`rbx` along with the three `pop`s and instead add a `pop rbp` before the `ret`. As Paul said, you should also add a `,0` after the `"%d"` although technically it works because you have zero after it anyway.

Comment: @Jester, the zero is overwritten with the first format conversion. fscanf then continues reading the format, which is now no longer null-terminated (for a few bytes, with ints laid-out in reverse in x86 memory)

Comment: I need to have push rbp,mov rbp,rsp,push rdi,push rsi, that is how I get from my proffessor but

Comment: It is funny because I write a complex code with these and I do not have problem now I write simple code and I have problem

Comment: Well you still need to add the `pop rbp`. If you have to keep those useless pushes (ask your professor why he insists on preserving caller-saved registers and `rbx` which is not even touched) then add another `push` to align the stack.

Comment: I will ask him, but I put that and I still get the same, do you know something, that I miss?

Comment: If you are intent on pushing all those unnecessary registers then this version should work: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/test53572475.asm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following issues:

1. You forgot to `pop rbp`.
2. You misalign the stack which needs to be 16 byte aligned.
3. You do not zero terminate your format string (thanks to Paul for pointing this out).
4. You use `%d` which writes a 4 byte integer but you only allocated 2 bytes with `dw`.
5. It is recommended to align integers to 4 bytes.

A possible fixed version:

```
section .data
number dd 0
text db 'Put a number',10,0
scanform db '%d', 0

section .text
extern printf,scanf

global main
main:
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
push rdi
push rsi
push rbx
push rbx ; for alignment

mov rdi,text
mov rax,0
call printf

mov rsi,number
mov rdi,scanform
mov rax,0
call scanf

pop rbx
pop rbx
pop rsi
pop rdi
pop rbp
ret
```

Since `rsi` and `rdi` are caller-saved registers and `rbx` is not touched, you can simplify the code. I also changed to `xor` zeroing and rip-relative addressing as follows:

```
section .data
number dd 0
text db 'Put a number',10,0
scanform db '%d', 0

section .text
extern printf,scanf

global main
main:
push rbp

lea rdi, [rel text]
xor eax, eax
call printf

lea rsi, [rel number]
lea rdi, [rel scanform]
xor eax, eax
call scanf

pop rbp
ret
```